# anchor opening element on separate page not working?

Tags: jquery-plugins, anchor, target

I am trying to get my anchors of thumbnails to open to a different page but at the specific element. I don't think it is working as there is a jquery plugin on the page that the elements exist on and I can't find a way to target them. When you click on a image it opens on the first in the sequence but not on the image requested. How can this be solved?

Please see my page here http://i-n-t-e-l-l-i-g-e-n-t-s-i-a.com/melissafranklin.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The href attribute of the `<a>` tag should match the src attribute of the `<img>` tag

Use this:

```
<a href="images/paintings/7copy.jpg">
  <img src="images/paintings/7copy.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Instead of this:

```
<a href="paintings.html">
  <img src="images/paintings/7copy.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I don't want the image file to open, I want the painting.html page to open at the correct image on the page. Any idea why href="paintings.html#img2" for example will not  open at image 2? Thanks

Comment: Just realised I made stupid mistake of not making sure the id's were right, and that is why it wasn't working!!